# C++ accepts wrong return-type

Tags: c++, gcc, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

I have the following code, which, in my opinion, should not compile:
(In a `class Vector` (**not** the `std::vector`, but a `Vector` that I defined myself)):

```cpp
Vector operator*(double factor)
{
  // some element-wise multiplication here
  return factor;
}
```

I am defining this operator to return a `Vector`, but inside the method i return a `double`.

I also have **not** defined any **implicit conversion operators** inside the class.

I would think that this is clearly not valid, but gcc happily compiles this, without any complaint at all.

My first reflex is to file a defect-report to gcc, but I thought I would ask here before..

Am I missing something here that would explain why this code is considered valid by the compiler?

(In case it's relevant, c++-standard is set to c++17)

Some more Info on the `Vector` class: (namely, I include all declared constructors and operators, as other, named functions should not contribute to this issue):

```cpp
class Vector {
public:
  Vector(std::vector<double> values);
  Vector(size_t dimension, double value);
  Vector(size_t dimension);

  void operator*=(double factor);
  void operator*=(Vector const& factor);

  friend Vector operator-(Vector const& a, Vector const& b);
  friend Vector operator+(Vector const& a, Vector const& b);
  friend Vector operator*(Vector const& a, Vector const& b);

  Vector operator*(double factor);
  double& operator[](size_t i);

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Vector const& v);
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the definition of `Vector` is hard to say if the code is valid or not.

Comment: No [mcve] - did not happen

Comment: at a guess `Vector` has a non-explicit single argument constructor that takes a numerical value, e.g: https://godbolt.org/z/EcTvGo

Comment: @AlanBirtles ooops.. 
Okay, that's it - it seems some people **can** read my mind.. :D
I wasn't even aware that implicit construction happens as well.. was only aware of implicit conversions, and of course implicit copy-constructions.. now that i think of it, the existence of implicit copy constructions hint at the existence of other implicit constructions...
I will update my question, to include the relevant info on the `Vector`-class, if someone posts the hint at non-explicit constructors as an answer, i will accept it, otherwise i'll answer myself, with the knowledge just gained.

Comment: "My first reflex is to file a defect-report to gcc" that should be your last reflex.

Comment: You should change the one constructor to `explicit Vector(size_t dimension);`.

Comment: @Eljay yeah, did already happen, thanks anyway! I would post this as an answer, but the post is locked, and i don't know if my edit will be considered suffiicient for it to be reopened

Comment: "I also have not defined any implicit conversion operators inside the class" Yes you did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing this answer on received comments:

Non-explicit conversion-operators are not the only way in which a return-value that initially has the wrong type may "become" the type needed for the function-signature.
The constructor

```cpp
Vector(size_t dimension);
```

Takes one numerical value as an argument, which itself is not a `double`, but a `long unsigned int`, but a `double` can be converted into that.

So what happens is that the `double factor` is first converted into a `long unsigned int` and then an implicit construction of `Vector`, using the constructor `Vector(size_t dimension);` happens.
The object that is the result of this construction is then returned.

Therefore, this is valid code in the sense of not breaking language-rules, the compiler is definitely not doing anything wrong here.

If this behaviour is not wanted, the constructor in question should be marked `explicit` like this:

```cpp
explicit Vector(size_t dimension);
```

If there were multiple constructors taking one argument of a type into which a `double` can be converted, or whose first arguments fulfill that requirement with all other arguments being optional, for example:

```cpp
Vector(int a, char b = 'c');
```

they would have to be marked `explicit` as well, but in that case it is likely that the compiler would complain, because it could not deduce which constructor to call.